# Navigation bar with retina image

Tags: ios, xcode

i'm trying to add an image to a navigation bar, i download the image through the Internet. If i take a 320x44 image it's all ok, but if i take a 640x88 image, so retina resolution, the image in the navigation bar is not resized and appears out of bounds.
I set the image with this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:im forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: How do you load the image?

Comment: Did you properly name the retina image with the `@2x` suffix?

Comment: I use a method that i created to download images from internet, i don't rename the image because i download it form internet

Comment: If you don't rename the image with `@2x` suffix it won't gonna work

Comment: If you just set the image in the navigation bar without adjusting the size then ios thinks you want to base the image size off of 1024*768.  "Retina" based images are loaded using "onscreen" sizes of half their resolution, then in the background ios shows the full resolution using video processing.  You need to somehow detect the image size and then modify the imageview's frame if the size indicates a "retina" image.  Given the method you are using you would have to have the @2x that everyone else mentioned.